# Wave-Modified Collision Object Not Changing

Tags: modifiers, physics

Please see a gif pic of my situation:

[image]

http://gph.is/2EwjmKs

The gif image shows that the ball responds only to the mesh-shaped collision object that is present at frame 1 in the first half of the gif picture.

In the second half, you can see the ball exhibits the same behavior without a moving mesh that's in the same shape as frame 1 in the first half of the gif pic.

How can I elicit a dynamically changing collision object for my wavy plane?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable 'Deforming' in the Rigid Body Collisions panel should do it.
[image]

[image]

Comment: lol Thanks a million, Mike Pan. Your suggestion is perfectly applicable to my answer quest and has relieved me of worry. Thanks again, you rock.